# LWJGL Texture Unbinding

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I'm currently working on a simple textured rectangle class using LWJGL (GL11). This is what I have so far in the draw method.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

color.bind();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

t.bind();

if (centered)
{
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
    glVertex2d(x - (width / 2), y - (height / 2));
    glTexCoord2d(t.getWidth(), 0);
    glVertex2d(x + (width / 2), y - (height / 2));
    glTexCoord2d(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
    glVertex2d(x + (width / 2), y + (height / 2));
    glTexCoord2d(0, t.getHeight());
    glVertex2d(x - (width / 2), y + (height / 2));
}
else
{
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
    glVertex2d(x, y);
    glTexCoord2d(t.getWidth(), 0);
    glVertex2d(x + width, y);
    glTexCoord2d(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
    glVertex2d(x + width, y + height);
    glTexCoord2d(0, t.getHeight());
    glVertex2d(x, y + height);
}
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The problem is with the second to last line (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`). If I leave this on, the image will display for a split second (probably one frame) and then turn solid white. If I comment this out, it will display, but always displays the last texture that was loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are binding your texture between the glBegin() and glEnd() calls. This is invalid. I'm guessing when you leave the glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) call off, then the binding is taking effect the next frame. Not sure why it would work for one frame, though.

You can use [glGetError](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetError.xml) to see if there are any errors generated.

Comment: I've moved it out to where I bind the color, no such luck. glGetError returns zero.